# Computing dask array chunks asynchronously (Dask + FastAPI)

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, fastapi, uvicorn

I am building a FastAPI application that will serve chunks of a Dask Array. I would like to leverage [FastAPI's asynchronous functionality](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/) alongside [Dask-distributed's ability to operate asynchronously](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/asynchronous.html). Below is a mcve that demonstrates what I'm trying to do on both the server and client sides of the application:

**Server-side:**

```py
import time

import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
import uvicorn
from dask.distributed import Client
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
# create a dask array that we can serve
data = da.from_array(np.arange(0, 1e6, dtype=np.int), chunks=100)


async def _get_block(block_id):
    """return one block of the dask array as a list"""
    block_data = data.blocks[block_id].compute()
    return block_data.tolist()


@app.get("/")
async def get_root():
    time.sleep(1)
    return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get("/{block_id}")
async def get_block(block_id: int):
    time.sleep(1)  # so we can test concurrency
    my_list = await _get_block(block_id)
    return {"block": my_list}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Client(n_workers=2)
    print(client)
    print(client.cluster.dashboard_link)
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=9000, log_level="debug")
```

**Client-side**

```py
import dask
import requests
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client()

responses = [
    dask.delayed(requests.get, pure=False)(f"http://127.0.0.1:9000/{i}") for i in range(10)
]
dask.compute(responses)
```

In this setup, the `compute()` call in `_get_block` is "blocking" and only one chunk is computed at a time. I've tried various combinations of `Client(asynchronous=True)` and `client.compute(dask.compute(responses)`) without any improvement. Is it possible to `await` the computation of the dask array?

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804)

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
block_data = data.blocks[block_id].compute()
```

is a blocking call. If you instead did `client.compute(data.blocks[block_id])`, you would get an awaitable future that can be used in conjunction with you IOLoop, so long as Dask is using the same loop.

Note that the Intake server would very much like to work in this manner (it too aspires to stream data by chunks for arrays and other data types).

Comment: Thanks @mdurant! Any tips on getting Dask and Uvicorn to use the same IOLoop?

Comment: No, I don't know. You *can* specify the ioloop when instantiating the client, but I don't know if that's enough.